# Multiple JOIN on query

Tags: mysql

I want to create a contact table that can be used later. So the structure:

```
table contact: id, contact_type
table contact_meta : id, contact_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

Is this query is a bad practice? (more than 10 join?)

```
select c.id, 
    cm1.meta_value as name,
    cm2.meta_value as email,
    cm3.meta_value as bussiness_phone
    from contact as c
    left join contact_meta as cm1 on (cm1.contact_id = c.id)
    left join contact_meta as cm2 on (cm2.contact_id = c.id)
    left join contact_meta as cm3 on (cm3.contact_id = c.id)
    where c.contact_type = 'supplier' and 
    cm1.meta_key = 'name' and 
    cm2.meta_key = 'email' and
    cm3.meta_key = 'bussiness_phone' ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Comment: Don't you have three joins there, not ten?

Comment: Well, it's bad practice because EAV is best avoided in relational databases, but sometimes there isn't an alternative, in which case the conventional approach is to adopt MAX(CASE WHEN THEN END) syntax. It's briefer (and probably faster). Also, as you have it, including the conditions in the WHERE clause will exclude NULL results which is probably not waht you want.

Comment: @BenM, there will be ten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not "bad practice", but move the extra conditions into the join clause where they belong:

```
select c.id, 
  cm1.meta_value as name,
  cm2.meta_value as email,
  cm3.meta_value as bussiness_phone
from contact as c
left join contact_meta as cm1 on cm1.contact_id = c.id and cm1.meta_key = 'name'
left join contact_meta as cm2 on cm2.contact_id = c.id and cm2.meta_key = 'email'
left join contact_meta as cm3 on cm3.contact_id = c.id and cm3.meta_key = 'bussiness_phone'
order by c.id desc
```

Note the removal of unnecessary brackets also.

Comment: Is it okay for the performance if i use it more than 3, like 10?

Comment: You have no option, so performance is not really a concern; you must do what you must do. As long as it performs "OK", don't worry about it.